# Figures not aligned vertically while using two subfigures horizontally

Tags: floats, overleaf

I am trying to set two subfigures a and be in the following way:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[a]{0.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/performance-deltasize-1.pdf}
  \caption{Minimal change}
  \label{fig:performance:deltasize:1} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/performance-deltasize-2.pdf}
  \caption{Real-life author changes}
  \label{fig:performance:deltasize:2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Delta size---minimal vs. real-life author changes: Delta size per algorithm applied to the same original JATS---once on the modified JATS with minimal text edit and once with real-life author changes}
\label{fig:performance:deltasize}
\end{figure}
```

However, I have some issues with the vertical alignment:
[image: example]

I have checked the order of label vs caption but I still have the same alignment issue.

Comment: Actually, [t] aligns the bottom (baseline) of the image, and [b] aligns the top (baseline) of the caption, so they look pretty much the same.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot both, that fixed my issue. I was thinking a and b are the figure labels. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you can write a quick answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the subcaption package, it's beset to include the minimum LaTeX code to illustrate your issue.  The optional arguments for the subfigure environment deal with positioning, not labeling the subfigures "a" or "b," which is done automatically.  The figures should be aligned if you delete "[a]" and "[b]."

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1.png}
  \caption{Minimal change}
  \label{fig:performance:deltasize:1} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill{}
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure2.png}
  \caption{Real-life author changes}
  \label{fig:performance:deltasize:2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Delta size---minimal vs. real-life author changes: Delta size per algorithm applied to the same original JATS---once on the modified JATS with minimal text edit and once with real-life author changes}
\label{fig:performance:deltasize}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]